# Dynamic json field schema with data mapping using C#

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, mapping

I get this type of JSON data from Web API:

```
Data: {
  FromDate: "2016-03-01",
  Comment: "Bla bla",
  ...
},
FieldInfo: {
  Items: [
  {
    Id: "FromDate",
    Required: true,
    DataType: "date"
  },
  {
    Id: "Comment",
    Required: true,
    DataType: "string"
  },
  ...
  ]
}
```

I need to serialize it to C# object and transform it to different representaion which should look something like this:

```
  {
    FieldInfo: {
      Items: [
      {
        Id: "FromDate",
        Required: true,
        DataType: "date",
        Value: "2016-03-01"
      },
      {
        Id: "Comment",
        Required: true,
        DataType: "string"
        Value: "Bla bla"
      },
      ...
      ]
   }
```

Basically map field values to its schema so it will not be separated.
Of course easiest way its just write a lot of if's for each field, which will not be very elegant solution and even not doable if we take into account that field schema and fields are dynamic so they can change. Property which I can rely on is Id in FieldInfo Item schema which should be a property name in Data object. One of the solution might be to use reflection in order to map Id value to property name in C# object representation. My question maybe there is another solution(s) to this problem or some tools which can help me in achieving this goal?

Comment: 1) Are the inputs and outputs supposed to be JSON?  Because they are invalid JSON according to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.  2) What have you tried so far?  If JSON, what are you using to parse / deserialize the incoming JSON and then later serialize after conversion?

Comment: Yes basically I have web API which calls another web API and I need to parse it transform and output transformed version of data. JSON which I provided is just for better understanding what I am trying to achieve. It is not valid as I added "..." in order to represent that you can have different field types, sorry if it added extra confusion.

Comment: 1) It's not just the missing quotes, the initial JSON is missing outer braces.  2) What framework and serializer are you using?  If you're using [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization) them are you already using Json.NET?

Comment: Yes it is ASP.NET Web API and Json.NET.

Answer (score 3):

Using [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), you can parse the JSON into a [JObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject.htm) and manipulate it like so:

```
// Parse your json string into a JObject
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

// Retrieve the "Data" part of the json, i.e, 
// the object that contains the values
var data = o["Data"];

// Retrieve the "FieldInfo" part. We will add values to this part.
var fieldInfo = o["FieldInfo"];

foreach (var token in fieldInfo["Items"])
{
    var item = (JObject) token;

    // Add the Value property to each item, get the value from the
    // corresponding field
    item["Value"] = data[(string)item["Id"]];
}
```

The variable fieldInfo will contain the information you wanted. Of course, it would be cleaner to create a new JObject to contain the information. But the example shows how you can retrieve and map the values you require.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement some form of custom json converter to get the required output you desire to your new class structure. [JSON.NET](http://JSON.net) Custom JsonConverter:

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Here is a nice beginners tutorial on how this is achieved:

http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidHoerster/archive/2011/07/26/json.net-custom-convertersndasha-quick-tour.aspx